# AES Decryption false positive?

Tags: encryption, aes

For now, I encrypt a lot of messages by multiple AES keys.
But message will be encrypted by only one AES key.
So, each AES key has own check-code to figure out this message is encrypted by it. Before the encryption, check-code is attached to message. After description, check check-code to see I choose proper key to descrypt.

But, I wonder if a Message, M  encrypted by key A(of course there is a check-code of A in front of M), can present check-code of B after decrypted by key B? Is it possible?

Thanks for reading a question.
I'm not good at english, if you have any problem to read, leave a reply. I give more information about the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends entirely on your check-code. Imagine your check-code is only 1 bit long, the chance that you get a false positive is 50%.<sup>1</sup>

However, this problem is well known under the name [Authenticated Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption). A lot of libraries have built-in functions for it that cover encryption and authentication (and integrity) at the same time.

I strongly recommend using a library that offers AE directly and not to combine multiple crypto primitives yourself. The reason AE was developed is the observation that implementations often made mistakes.

---

<sup>1</sup>I think this statement is not completely correct, but the gist of it should be.

Comment: The advantage of AE(AD) ciphers or a manual construct of HMAC/SHA-* over the *cipher text* is that the authentication tag (what the OP is calling "check-code") can be verified *before* attempting to decrypt unknown cipher text. This reduces the attack vector of a chosen cipher text attack (CCA), and guarantees that the cipher text was not modified in transit. Ensure you use a *constant-time* equality check for the auth tag to avoid leaking timing information.